# Dynamic UILabel size for view before uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, autolayout, uilabel

I am having abit of trouble here trying to make this post description label to grow and shrink based on content size on IOS9. I have a view (I will refer it topView) that I am using as a header for the tableview (So when I scroll up the header disappears). Inside the topView, there are a bunch of stack views. I wish to grow and shrink the post description label in height based on content size. I do know how to do it in simple case where everything is inside the prototype cell (i.e. set estimated row height and set uitableviewautomaticDimensions, set sizetoFit on label and change number of lines to 0). However, this is a different case because the post description label is not really inside the cell, it is in its view before the table view cells.

Note that all items in the view has static height except the postdescription label. Post description label is inside a stack view that is pinned only left and right (So that top and bottom would grow?). Also, the main stack view that contains all elements is pinned towards the four sides with the topview that contains the main stack view also pinned towards the four sides. With this setup, I would expect the topview to grow and shrink based on the content size. However, I do not see that in the output. I dont know if it is the stackview that is holding the label refusing to grow or the top view refusing to grow to allow more space for the stackview for the label. Thanks

[image: dynamic uilabel]

UPDATE

Thanks Riadluke, I tried doing something as suggested which is resizing the headerview after calculating the required height. I have placed the following code in viewDidLayoutSubview and it works with an issue

```
postDescriptionLbl.sizeToFit()


let headerView = commentTableView.tableHeaderView!

headerView.setNeedsLayout()
headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

let height = TopStackView.frame.size.height + ImageStackView.frame.size.height + postDescriptionLbl.frame.size.height + SpacerStackView.frame.size.height + BottomStackView.frame.size.height
 headerView.frame.size.height = height
commentTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

The issue I now have with this method is that when the view controller appears, I can physically see the postDescription label height grow from the default height in storyboard to the required height. For example, when the VC first appears, I see a line of label with some string being cut off, however after 0.5 second, the headerview and the label grow to the size that I wanted. I know this would be expected because I was calling the manipulation after the viewDidLayout Subview. I was wondering if there is a better way such that I dont see that transition and the view appears to be the right height straight away. Ie. let the view know exactly how high the label is to determine how high the headerview needs to be before appearing on screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the view set as `tableHeaderView` of a `UITableView` does not get resized automatically. Its height will be fixed to the height it had in IB.
What you have to do is set its size manually and then reassign it as the tableHeaderView so it is displayed in the height you want.

It could take only few lines since you're using autolayout.
You can try this code right after you've set the header view's contents:

```
    //for the target size you have set the width as your tableView's width when it is already displayed on screen.
    //note that when it is accesed inside viewDidLoad the tableView's bounds
    //may be different to the actual bounds it will be displayed with,
    //here I am just using the screen bounds
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 10000)

    //set the tableHeader's size to its size after its layout constraints are resolved
    tableHeader.bounds.size =  tableHeader.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(targetSize)

    //reassign it as the tableHeaderView to update the height it will be displayed in
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader
```

Comment: Thanks for the response riahluke. Any idea about the update above? Thanks

Comment: have you tried systemLayoutFittingSize and call it inside viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

After many many attempts, I could not get anything to work with the original setup. The best I achieved was to resize it after view did appear which is not idea as you see the previous layout.

It is now working with a complete different approach. I have created two prototype cell and have one as "HeaderViewCell" and implemented the following functions

```
commentTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 400
commentTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
```

Everything works like a charm after that.